# Can't send emails

Tags: config, emails, install, registration

I've got an "escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons" warning whenever I try to send an email using Craft (user activation email), is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, just use settings->email and setup SMTP or POP3 account duh. I'll leave it here just in case someone is as forgetful as me.